# Why two different macros functions share variable namespace in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

The code below won't compile, because of redeclaration of the `let a` variable.

But if the second `test` template commented out it would work.

Why it works that way, and how to fix it?

[playground](https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=2Lys)

```
template test*(name: string, body) =
  block: body

template test*(name: string, group: string, body) =
  block: body

test "a1":
  let a = 1

test "a2":
  let a = 1
```

Comment: Seems like a bug to me, you should open an issue. I noticed that changing `test "a2":` to `test "a2", "g1":`, it works again.

Comment: @pietroppeter thanks, I created the issue https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/16680

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The body argument to the first template gets typechecked as there is an overload on it where there is a typed argument in the same place. I think your best option for now is to remove the : string annotation on group. To fix this Nim needs to alter its overload semantics in a case like this where it's obvious the arities don't match, but that might be unpredictable.

Thanks to `hlaaftana` for providing the answer in the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/issues/16680#issuecomment-757855731)

So the fixed code would be:

```
template test*(name: string, body) =
  block: body

template test*(name: string, group, body) =
  block: body

test "a1":
  let a = 1

test "a2":
  let a = 1
```